# What are the advantages of showing line numbers in a text editor?

Tags: ide

I feel weird when I'm editing code in an IDE that does not have line numbers in the text editor.

The questions I have are:

1. Are line numbers visually excessive, particularly when a find by line function exists in your IDE of choice?
2. What are the uses of showing line numbers?

Comment: 2: Feel totally macho over number of lines of code written.

Comment: @AdamCrossland: funny you should mention that, I typically see it as exactly the opposite and the more lines of code I write, the more time I end up spending looking over it to make sure I didn't do anything twice and that I'm meeting spec.

Comment: yeah that's all true for me too, but sometimes you just have to strap on your motorcycle helmet and go for the macho.

Comment: Line numbers make goto-statements in code possible. That's the main reason to have them. Later they evolved to an ability to move inside large single file based on compiler error messages.

Comment: I find it faster to scroll with an eye on the line numbers than use the goto line function of my editor (that might be because I first have to find it each time), especially when I'm already close

Comment: @ratchet freak, most editors use Ctrl-G to go to a specific line

Comment: @chad that should tell you how little I use it ;)

Comment: I normally use line numbers, but with many web languages such as PHP, they can be misleading when and if you receive an error. Just because PHP claims the error is on line 24 doesn't mean it corresponds to the same line number in your editor.

Comment: @Oranges13: You can't possibly be serious.

Comment: @Adam : Feel totally Macho at how _few_ lines of codes I have written to make it work.

Comment: When the compiler tells you an error is on a particular line number, I like to know I'm on that line.

Comment: @Jesse: in the context of IDEs you are usually one click away from the line, so it is less useful (visually) in this circumstance.

Comment: @Matthieu: no argument.  But not everything is in the context of an IDE.  Like a report from a continuous integration build server, for instance.

Comment: @Jesse: ah, too bad... that said I am using an external compiler myself, thankfully my editors have short-cut to quickly jump at a line.

Comment: Same advantage to having page numbers in a book...for reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Anything that aids communication is a plus.**

1. It doesn't take up much space so no, it's not excessive if you or any of your colleagues find it useful to discuss the code.
2. Even if you don't do pair programming, it is useful for "over the shoulder" code reviews if you don't use tools like Code Collaborator (we don't right now).

Also if you have team members in other sites (we do), it's useful for discussing code via IM or on the phone.

How can you tell them tell them to go to line 1842 if you can't see the line?

For me it's an invaluable simple little tool. Even some of our pdf specs have numbered lines, and it's amazing how much easier it is to refer to and discuss compared to the unnumbered ones.

Answer (score 54):

Nobody mentioned being able to quickly look at an exception stack trace to find out where an exception occurred.

Comment: Really? OP states `"referencing stack trace line numbers"`. Or are you both referring to different things?

Comment: Oops... I missed that!  Well... its important so it is worth reiterating! ;)

Comment: Well the question's been edited now, upvote ahoy!

Comment: And of course, looking at *logs* (not necessarily from exceptions). All our logs index the file + line they originate from, incredibly handy!

Comment: @maple_shaft, Actually even when you are not able to see lines, you can **still** do Ctrl-G (e.g. plain old notepad).

Answer (score 51):

Displayed line numbers are essential for paired-programming. There is no faster way to direct your pair's eyes to the code you are thinking about.

By extension, line-numbers are also extremely useful for code-reviews, both formal and informal.

Comment: +1: Hadn't considered paired programming (not surprising though as I'm definitely not a fan). However, the usefulness of line numbers in code reviews is pretty much turfed if you use an application for it (such as CodeCollaborator)

Comment: I wasn't in the habit of line numbering until I'd done a bit of pair programming, now I'm in the habit of line numbering. +1 for getting me to realize this connection.

Comment: Rather than saying *"Lines 247 to 253,"* I find it faster to just highlight those lines, or point to them with my finger.  I don't feel this answer is enough to justify the extra clutter.

Comment: I'm stunned that this answer received 36 upvotes in 24 hours.

Comment: @BlueRaja: not sure of pair programming either (though you could have both hands occupied), but when discussing from one desk to another, it definitely helps! *There's something I don't understand in yyy.cpp at line 314, why do we need that ?*

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't think that rare case justifies the clutter either.  For those cases, most editors have a "Goto line" feature *(`Edit-->Goto` or `ctrl+g` in Visual Studio)*.  Also, you should prefer method names to line numbers - who says their copy of the code still has the same line numbers?

Comment: @BlueRaja: (CTRL+L in Eclipse :p) but how do they know the line number if not displayed :) ? The method name is great, but the line number is faster to communicate and points right at the interesting statement instead of *that second `for` loop within `Foo::bar`, the second overload*.

Comment: @Eric, Ik right O_o ?!  Me too with my answer.  I am amazed that we can state a seemingly obvious one sentence answer, but then a well researched page long answer will get 1 vote.

Answer (score 10):

1. No, I like having the data to give me an idea of where is something in a file, especially if I'm looking at a big configuration file where it may not be easy to find that spot again.
2. I may glance at the line number as a way for me to see how big is a file.  If there are a few thousand lines of code in a file then it may be time to consider if that file should be broken up or something.  I can also use it to judge how deep am I in a file if I have a ballpark of the file size and which numbers are on my screen.  I like the idea of quantifying my location within the scroll bar, e.g. I'm in the top quarter of the file or 3rd quintile.

Comment: A few *thousand*?

Comment: @Anthony: You should see loc per file in a game ;)

Comment: @Anthony: sure. I've seen source files with 10k+ LOC, easily.

Comment: @tdammers, so have I. The issue is not whether these files exists, it's the point of when is the time to start reconsidering. In my view, that's normally *well* before a few thousand. It's well before a few *hundred*. In fact, once I start scrolling, I start to feel a bit antsy (doesn't mean I immediately refactor, mind you).

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - I feel that a program should be well structured via functions/routines et cetera. The fact that they are all in the same file does not bother me; quite the opposite; I prefer them all in there instead of a plethora of files in one directory. Easier to diff too, IMO.

Comment: @Rook, Definitely. If you have everything in one file, the quality usually increases because It's easier to ensure that you don't have some stray code in some stray file somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

I've come from a history of using editors with line numbers embedded in them. My thoughts on the matter? They're absolutely unneeded (I now use Vim with line numbers disabled). Think about this: Even when you *do* get stack traces and such, how many times do you manually *look* for the line using line numbers as opposed to `ctrl+g` (in most Windows editors) or `:line-num` in Vim?

Edit: Of course, this may be different for others, but 99% of the time, I use the latter.

Answer (score 7):

One big thing: If you're using Visual studio or any ide with collapsible regions, line numbers give you an instant feel for how big an area is without expanding it.
In addition, if you have some sort of logging directing you to a problem line, it's nice to not need to use a command when it's the line is right in front of you.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason (cross compiling comes to mind) your compiler may not be integrated into your IDE. Therefore you need an absolute reference for where errors are found. (When you compile outside of your IDE)

NWS

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've used line numbers is when a bug pops up and the stack trace tells me that it has happened at line x.

I've seen many professional developers working without line-numbers. So, I see no usage other than **late referencing**.

Answer (score 2):

I like to have it when I use split screen in jEdit.

Comment: +1 It definitely helps to orient split screen work in the same file! There are few other ways to determine whether you are looking at the reference or the working area of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @maple_host says, it's really convenient to do a "vi file.py +142" when I see an exception originating from code at that line number. Plus the other mentioned advantages with paired programming etc... It is always beneficial to have the line numbers on, on any editor. (I remember the vague compile error reported by MS VC++ 6 in one of the standard header files, line #blah!!.. It was actually a macro redefinition done by myself!!). Find and kill.

regards,
Yati Sagade

Answer (score -1):

I've found that [current line highlighting](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/05/16/visual-studio-usability-tip-highlight-current-line.aspx) can solve most "where are you looking" problems. But, the point about stack traces is critical.